# Open executable with php

Tags: php, c++, exec, executable

How to open executable (GNU/Linux) with php?

`exec` and `system` are not working for me.

Since I have tried multiple different options, I'm here to ask you. I never had any experience with php (I work with C), so I'm stuck at probably something simple, yet so hard for me. I have tried this:

```
<?php

string exec('add_user email password');

?>
```

and many other possibilities.
add_user is an executable written in C++. It is located in root folder, in html folder and apache2 folder (just in case), so it's not the path at fault. Email and password are parameters. I have tried both exec() and system(), nothing happens. I have even tried 'whoami', nothing. When I says nothing happens, I really mean it. I call the php with browser "localhost/test.php", just get blank site. If I try `echo 'string';` i still get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```